# Transferring sessions from a files to the database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, migrate

I have accumulated over 60 million sessions, which led to the fact that file descriptors ran out.
The problem was solved by transferring sessions to the database.

Tested on Laravel 5.6.

For this:

1. [Prepare tables](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#database)

   php artisan session:table

   php artisan migrate
2. Create [Artisan Console command](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan)

In the App\Console\Commands directory, create a SessionMigrate.php file with the following content:

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Console\Commands;
    
    use Illuminate\Console\Command;
    use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
    use Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressBar;
    
    class SessionMigrate extends Command
    {
        
        protected $signature = 'migrate:sessions';
    
        
        protected $description = 'Migrate sessions from files to database';
    
        protected $files;
        protected $table;
        protected $connection;
    
       
        public function __construct(Filesystem $files)
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->files = $files;
            $this->table = config('session.table');
            $this->connection = DB::connection(config('session.connection'));
        }
    
        /**
         * Execute the console command.
         *
         * @return int
         */
        public function handle()
        {
            $this->info("Obtain session files...");
            
            $dir = config('session.files');
            
            $sessions_count = $this->getSessionsCount($dir);
            
            if(FALSE == $dir_res = opendir($dir))
            {
                $this->error("Sessions directory open error.");
                return 1;
            }
            
            
            $lifetime = config('session.lifetime');
            
            $inserted_count = 0;
            $updated_count = 0;
            $errors = 0;
            
            $this->info('Found ' . $sessions_count . ' session files');
            
            $bar = $this->output->createProgressBar($sessions_count);
            $bar->start();
            
        
            while (FALSE !== ($file = readdir($dir_res)))
            {
                $file_path = $dir.'/'.$file;
                
                if (in_array($file, array('.', '..')) || is_dir($file_path))
                { 
                    continue;
                }
                
                $id = $file;
                
                try
                {
                    $content = file_get_contents($file_path);
                    
                    $data = @unserialize($content);
                        
                    if(is_array($data))
                    {
                        $login_name = 'login_web_' . sha1(SessionGuard::class);
                        $user_id = NULL;
                        
                        if(array_key_exists($login_name, $data))
                        {
                            $user_id = $data[$login_name];
                        }
                        
                        $exists = $this->checkExists($id);
                        $last_activity = filemtime($file_path);
                        
                        if($exists)
                        {
                            
                            $this->connection->table($this->table)->whereId($id)->update([
                                'user_id'   => $user_id,
                                'payload'   => base64_encode($content),
                                'last_activity' => $last_activity
                            ]);
                           
                            $updated_count++;
                        }
                        else
                        {   
                            
                            $this->connection->table($this->table)->insert([
                                'id'        => $id,
                                'user_id'   => $user_id,
                                'payload'   => base64_encode($content),
                                'last_activity' => $last_activity
                            ]);
                            
                            $inserted_count++;
                        }
                    
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception $e)
                {
                    $errors++;
                }
                                    
                $bar->advance();
            }
            closedir($dir_res);
            
            
            $bar->finish();
    
            
            $this->table(
                ['Total session files', 'Created', 'Updated', 'Errors'],
                [
                    [$sessions_count, $inserted_count, $updated_count, $errors]
                ]
            );
            
            return 0;
        }
        
        protected function checkExists($id)
        {
            return (bool)$this->connection->table($this->table)->whereId($id)->first();
        }
        
        protected function getSessionsCount(string $dir)
        {
            $result = 0;
            
            if(FALSE == $dir_res = opendir($dir))
            {
                $this->error("Directory open error. ($dir)");
                return 0;
            }
            
            while (($file = readdir($dir_res)) !== false)
            {
                if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..')) && !is_dir($dir.$file))
                { 
                    $result++;
                }
            }
            
            closedir($dir_res);
            
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

3. Run the migration script

   php artisan migrate:sessions
4. Clear the Laravel config cache

   php artisan config:cache
5. Done.

Comment: Or just delete any expired session files?

Comment: Is there a question or is this some kind of how-to?

Comment: @kopz, You can delete sessions, but then your clients will be logged out and they will have to log in again. It can have a negative impact on sales.

Comment: @Sergey  I said expired session files not all session files

Comment: Thanks for this post ! If someone could explain performances issues (if any) with database session driver ? For 1M+ entries, is that significant to make the app slower ?