# Will session persist if I change the session driver from file to database in production Laravel site which is having traffic?

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am using the Laravel site in production with the session driver as file. The site has traffic with many sessions stored in file.
Now I want to change the session driver from file to database, will there be any issue with the user using my site? Will the previous session persist for the users?

If not then, Is there any way I can shift from Laravel session driver from file to database without losing previously stored sessions in files?

Comment: If you move to another city, can your friends still visit you in your old house?

Comment: why do you want previously stored session in files, if you want to move to alternate session process?

Comment: I want to persist session so that the currently logged in user do not get logged out automatically and they should be logged in when I change session driver.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the sessions will not persist when changing drivers. Users have to start a new session.

While it could be technically possible, I think it is difficult to migrate session files from one storage method to another. You would need to create a importer for all the session files, and then map these entries to the database, using the session file name and the session file contents.

Comment: is there any possible way I can migrate session files to database session?

Comment: I have no experience with this, though I think you can technically write a command that imports all files from the sessions file directory of your application. 

For each of these files, you could try and recreate the session data in the database (you probably need file name and the contents of the session file). Perhaps someone else can come up with a real solution, or you could try this out yourself and see if you run into any problems.

Comment: Hi, I found one here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67759420/transferring-sessions-from-a-files-to-the-database-in-laravel